# Finding an expression to represent this pattern

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

Is there a method to find a math expression for a given pattern? I have this pattern and I am very curious to find out how can I generate it.

`0
1     -1x
3     -4x      3x^2
5     -9x      9x^2        -5x^3
7     -16x     21.6x^2     -16x^3        7x^4
9     -25x     42.86x^2    -42.86x^3     25x^4     -9x^5
11    -36x     75x^2       -95.24x^3     75x^4     -36x^5     11x^6`

Comment: The first column are the odd integers (save 0), and the second column are the negative perfect squares. As for the rest of them...

Comment: You really need to tell us more about the source of these numbers. In particular, are the decimal numbers rounded or exact?

Comment: The decimal numbers are exact. And if it helps, this is from a physics problem where each line of these coefficients are describing interference patterns of corresponding interaction order.

Comment: "The decimal numbers are exact" and "this is from a physics problem" don't go together well. - Are you sure tha $-75$ in the last line shouldn't be $75$?

Comment: My mistake, I corrected the minus sign. I also put the x variables into it.  @HagenvonEitzen Why you think it can't be a physical problem?

Comment: If the sequence is exact, then how do you know it is exact if it was not generated by some underlying mathematical model?  That raises the question of how it was generated.  If it was empirically observed, then how can you claim the measurements are exact?

Comment: @heropup This sequence is the analytically calculated and simplified outcome of a physical problem, which is a particular interference pattern of up to 6 interacting particles. So there is an underlying math, but it doesn't directly tell anything about this sequence either.

Comment: Well, if there is some sort of mathematics that generated this array of values, then that would be the natural starting point to investigate if there is a way to tease out a pattern, either by finding some way to analytically simplify the formula(s), or to generate much larger arrays of values from which to extrapolate an identity.

Answer (score 0):

- The n-th row has *n* elements, starting with the first.
- The signs alternate on each row, and each row starts with a $+$.
- The first and last element of each row (starting with the second) host the odd numbers $2n-3$.
- The second and next-to-last element on each row (starting with the third) host the perfect squares $(n-1)^2$. Notice that the differences of each two consecutive squares are exactly the odd numbers mentioned before.
- The third and the next-to-next-to-last element on each row (starting with the fifth) host a number whose absolute value is very close to the arithmetic mean of the absolute values of the one to the side, and the one right above it, minus $4$.
- As far as the element in the middle of the seventh row is concerned, I need to see more rows before determining a specific pattern.
- Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. But the main puzzle is really the decimal numbers. Writing the next rows gonna be an extremely lengthy calculations and I can't do it quickly.